# NotePad ++ replace only in the next few lines

Tags: notepad++

How can I replace the text only in the next, for example, 5 lines?
For example, I want to replace the TITLE only in the next 5 lines, not in the whole document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

- Select the 5 lines
- In the Replace dialog, select the check-box named
  "In selection"
- Click Replace All.